# patching multiple module variables in all tests

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I have a module with two module variables. I want to path them out for all tests in my file. Initially I did monkey patching but this turned out to be a problem for tests in other files, that require those variables to be intact.
This is something I came up with currently. It's horrible but it works. I'd like to do something that's more "by the book" though (i.e. something that will keep a single indent for all the variables I patch):

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(autouse=True)
def stub_module_variables():
    with patch.object(my_module, 'old_first_variable', new=new_first_variable):
        with patch.object(my_module, 'old_second_variable', new=new_second_variable):
            yield
```

Comment: why do you that this is horrible?

Comment: I assume you want a pytest specific answer?  (e.g. _not_ a `unittest` answer?)  If that's the case, we should probably add the `pytest` tag if there is one ...)

Comment: It indents with every variable I patch. "Horrible" is maybe a wrong word here, but I feel like the proper way to do that would be something that keeps a single indent.

Comment: [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) accepts multiple with items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I feel like the proper way to do that would be something that keeps a single indent.

**With statement with multiple contexts**

You can put several statements into a single `with`

```
with patch.object(my_module, 'old_first_variable', new=new_first_variable), patch.object(my_module, 'old_second_variable', new=new_second_variable):
    # your code here, single indent
```

**With statement with multiple context, spanning multiple lines**

Obviously your lines can get very long, here's a way to break them down that still complies with PEP8

```
with patch.object(my_module, 'old_first_variable', new=new_first_variable), \
     patch.object(my_module, 'old_second_variable', new=new_second_variable), \
     patch.object(my_module, 'old_third_variable', new=new_third_variable):
    # Your code here, single indent
    pass
```

I ran `pep8` on a file with above snippet, it passes.

Comment: I tried this but I get `AttributeError: __exit__` on the line with second patch

Comment: Hmm that works, but I'm not sure why. Could you explain a bit? Also the syntax makes the indentation a little weird but I'll have to live with it I guess.

Comment: It's explained in the PEP8 link, PEP8 defines style guidelines, and part of it is to have an extra indent to distinguish it from the body of the block.

Comment: @iknownothing Can you use Python 3? There's another way you may like better.

Comment: I didn't mean the indent explanation (I'll live with it). I just don't understad why it doesn't work without the "as" part, but it worked without it when I used nested with statments.
I cannot use Python 3 sadly.

Comment: @iknownothing I've edited, the above snippet takes multiple contexts on multiple lines in the `with` statement. No extra indent, and `as` not required. I think this is the best we can do for Python 2. Because breaking this into multiple lines with parenthesis isn't going to be pretty.